# Django Admin super slow selecting single record

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have `Pick` model which when I select a record within Django Admin takes an age (about 20 seconds) to retrieve the record (there are about 70k).  However, it is quick when I try and create/save a record. I have added the indexes to try and speed up retrieval but don't really know what I should be doing

```
class Pick (models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    contest_entry=models.ForeignKey(ContestEntry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    game_round=models.ForeignKey(GameRound, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)

    objects = DataFrameManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'%s %s' % (self.contest_entry, self.game_round)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'contest_entry', 'game_round']
        ordering = ['contest_entry','game_round','user','team']
        index_together = [["user", "contest_entry", 'game_round'],]
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['user', 'contest_entry', 'game_round']),
            models.Index(fields=['game_round'], name='game_round_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['contest_entry'], name='contest_entry_idx'),
        ]

class PickAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Pick
    list_filter= (
        ('user', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('contest_entry__contest', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('game_round', RelatedDropdownFilter)
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related('user','contest_entry','game_round')
admin.site.register(Pick, PickAdmin)
```

How can I improve performance here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is specifying the [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) on the admin class. The default `<select>` widget for foreign key relationships can cause a lot of overhead retrieving and rendering all the options.

```
class PickAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Pick
    list_filter= (
        ('user', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('contest_entry__contest', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('game_round', RelatedDropdownFilter)
    )
    raw_id_fields = ('user', 'contest_entry', 'game_round',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related('user','contest_entry','game_round')
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that what takes so long is rendering the dropdowns for the `ForeignKey` fields of your model.

I'd suggest looking at the SQL queries that are performed, either by installing Django toolbar or enabling logging in your database server.

Comment: It is not the page with the dropdowns that takes time.  It is when I then select an item from the remaining list available, for example I might be calling `https://example.com/admin/contests/pick/1013/change`.  This page has no filters - it is simply the change page for the model `Pick`

Comment: That is what I mean. The dropdowns on the change/detail page where you select user, contest_entry and game_rounds. Django has to fetch all the data, and even if the query is fast, it takes long to render the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the queries by using select_related for foreignkeys https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Tried adding this to admin as shown in edit, but it is now slower on the relevant detail page